# How to parsegju,jk

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have to parse a TSV file which has the following structure:
[Secti
"1    2"
"2    3"his?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but it probably has to do with using an image instead of formatted text for the sample data.

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474975/csvhelper-does-not-parse-my-tab-delimited-csv-file

Either way, in the reader configuration you can set the delimiter to be anything you want, in your case "\t"

Comment: I manage to set the CSV info as a code. Thank you!

Comment: Are `[Section one of info]` and `[Section two of info]` part of the CSV file?  If not, is there any delimiter between the two sections?  Also, is it true that each entire row is bracketed in double-quotes like so?  `"1    2"`?

Comment: @dbc yeap they are aprt of the CSV file and regarding the double-quotes this is what I get when I try open the file with Notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were trying to do or not.  I also noticed that it appeared to be 4 spaces between records.  If it is actually a tab, you can change the delimiter to a tab `Delimiter = "\t",`

```cs
void Main()
{
    var data = @"[Section one of info]
""Atr1    1""
""Atr2    2""
[Section two of info]
""Atr3    Atr4""
""1    2""
""2    3""
""4    5""";

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "    ",
        Mode = CsvMode.Escape
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader(data))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var isSectionOne = true;
        var record = new Foo() { Atr3 = new List<int>(), Atr4 = new List<int>() };
        
        while(csv.Read())
        {
            if (csv.GetField(0).StartsWith("["))
                continue;
                
            if (isSectionOne)
            {
                if (csv.GetField(0) == "Atr1")
                {
                    record.Atr1 = csv.GetField<int>(1);
                }
                if (csv.GetField(0) == "Atr2")
                {
                    record.Atr2 = csv.GetField<int>(1);
                }
                if (csv.GetField(0) == "Atr3")
                {
                    isSectionOne = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                record.Atr3.Add(csv.GetField<int>(0));
                record.Atr4.Add(csv.GetField<int>(1));
            }           
        }
        record.Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Atr1 { get; set; }
    public int Atr2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> Atr3 { get; set; }
    public List<int> Atr4 { get; set; }
}
```